# Laravel - call to undefined method illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindshared()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I installed codeception and same other packages. before I install them, I can run `composer update` or `php artisan` normally without having any errors. But once I installed them suddenly when I run `composer update` or `php artisan` it results in this `bindshared()` error and I've no idea how to fix this.

here's my `composer.json` file :

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "laravelcollective/html" : "~5.2",
    "laracasts/commander": "~1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "doctrine/dbal" : "2.5.*",
    "laracasts/generators": "^1.1",
    "laracasts/testdummy": "~2.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}}
```

here's my `app.php` file :

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Environment
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This value determines the "environment" your application is currently
| running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure various
| services your application utilizes. Set this in your ".env" file.
|
*/

'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Debug Mode
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
| stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
| application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
|
*/

'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
| the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
| your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
|
*/

'url' => 'http://localhost',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone' => 'UTC',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Locale Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
| by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
| to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
|
*/

'locale' => 'en',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Fallback Locale
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
| is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
| the language folders that are provided through your application.
|
*/

'fallback_locale' => 'en',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Encryption Key
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
| to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
| will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
|
*/

'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Logging Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure the log settings for your application. Out of
| the box, Laravel uses the Monolog PHP logging library. This gives
| you a variety of powerful log handlers / formatters to utilize.
|
| Available Settings: "single", "daily", "syslog", "errorlog"
|
*/

'log' => env('APP_LOG', 'single'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Autoloaded Service Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
| request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
| this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
|
*/

'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    Laracasts\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider::class,
    Laracasts\Commander\CommanderServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Aliases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
| is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
| the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
|
*/

'aliases' => [

    'App'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Cache'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'Config'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent'  => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Gate'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
    'Hash'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Lang'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Password'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'URL'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    'Form'      => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html'      => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,

],
];
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this and why this error shows up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `laravelcollective/html` instead of `Html/Illuminate`.

First remove/comment out the following lines from app.php

```
'Form' => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

and

```
 Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

Now add this in your compoer.json, also remove `html/illuminate`

```
{
    "require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.2"
    }
}
```

Then add:

First remove/comment out the following lines from app.php

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

and

```
 Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

Then `composer update`.

Now add back or remove comment from the `app.php`

Do a composer `dump-autoload`.

Comment: i already used `laravelcollective\html` and added form and html and also `Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,` at app.php and still that bindshared() errors shows up

Comment: Did you remove those from `composer.json`,  and `app.php` ?

Comment: do you have any idea what's the problem that i encounter? and how to fix this?

Comment: A quick and easy fix would be navigate to the error page and replace `bindShared()` with `$app->singleton()`.

Comment: it seems `laracasts\commander` which gives me bindShared() error. it runs back to normal when i remove commander package. your answers is useful though.

Comment: To fix it .i executed `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload -o`

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps

step:1 
Illuminate folder

step:2 Html subfolder

step:3 HtmlServiceProvider.php

step:4 Replace bindShared by singleton

done.